# How to hand over my Object-Types in a correct way?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

in the following method, I try to select specific IDs from one type of object. All above works, but the last part, where i hand the objects from query to a list of the specific object Type (T) makes problems, also the following methodes do not accept my input. I could imagine, on runtime this should all work fine, but visual-studio does not accept it.

```
    private static Guid[] SelectiveQuery<T>(Guid[] ga, T input, string a)
    {
        List<T> li = new List<T>();

        foreach (Guid g in ga)
        {
            var query = from produkt in Entity.ProduktCollection.produktCollection
                        let p = produkt as Entity.Produkt
                        from version in p.version
                        let v = version as Entity.Version
                        from customer in v.customerCollection
                        let c = customer as Entity.Customer
                        from fehler in v.fehlerCollection
                        let f = fehler as Entity.Fehler
                        select new {p, v, c, f};

            switch (a)
            {
                case "produkt":
                    query = query.Where(x => x.p.id == g); break;
                case "version":
                    query = query.Where(x => x.v.id == g); break;
                case "customer":
                    query = query.Where(x => x.c.id == g); break;
                case "fehler":
                    query = query.Where(x => x.f.id == g); break;
                case "kategorie":
                    query = query.Where(x => x.f.kategorie.id == g); break;
            }

            query = query.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T));

                li.AddRange(query); //contains error ("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>" can't be converted to "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>"
        }
        // Reduce() removes duplicates in li and returns the list
        li = Reduce(li, i => i.id); //contains error (T doesn't contain a definition for id)
        // Guids() makes a list of all IDs inside li and returns this List<Guid>
        return Guids(li, i => i.id); //contains error (T doesn't contain a definition for id)
    }
```

Comment: For the "T doesn't contain a definition for id", I think you should use a "where T:" with an Interface that defines that id must be available.

Comment: @Thomas W. could you give an example? I'm not quiet sure that i know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a ToList() statement to the where statement?

```
query = query.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T)).ToList();
```

As I recall the result of the Where statement is a too generic collection and therefore it needs to be cast first.

Since I see that you're using an AddRange, it could also need to be converted to an array, use the ToArray() statement instead of the ToList() statement if the first doesn't work. I'm not sure if you can provide a List to an AddRange() statement.

Comment: I've looked a bit further into it and I believe it has something to do with the result of select new {p, v, c, f}.

I don't know what that result will contain, but can't you stick that into a defined class?

X can be an instance of that class, so the query will contain a collection of that class. I also believe this class must be a base class for T